# Php error "Undefined variable:post" when using "get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)"

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

I have a line of php to get the thumbnail image in my custom wordpress widget:

```
$footer_recent_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'footer-recent-thumbnail' );
```

It produces two php errors:

```
NOTICE: customwidgets.php:75 - Undefined variable: post
NOTICE: customwidgets.php:75 - Trying to get property of non-object
```

How can I resolve this?  It is the same php I use to get the thumbnail on the blog and it doesn't give an error there.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($post);` ? That variable doesn't seem to be declared

Comment: 1. There is no variable (here object) = $post. 2. That's why you get the second notice also. So $post does not exist (here). Likely, it is definded in your "blog" but not in this scope.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My guess would be that this code is in a function, like so:

```
function doSomething($someparams) {
     // ...
     $fotoer_recent_thumb = // .....
     // ...
}
```

In this case, `$post` does not exist in this scope, and must be imported by adding the following line inside your function:

```
global $post;
```

Alternatively, and more cleanly, pass it as a parameter.

Comment: I was just using it inside the while have posts loop, but adding "global $post;" did remove the errors.  Is that the best way to do it when not using a function?

Answer (score 4):

Try this way:

```
if (has_post_thumbnail()) { 
    $footer_recent_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 
        get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()) , 'footer-recent-thumbnail'
    );

    // Do more stuff
}
```